# InstagramAPI returns only part of the user's followers list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, instagram-api

I wrote a python code using InstagramAPI to get all my following and followers lists. I managed to get a list of all the people I follow - the list contains 292 users out of 292 users I follow. 
However, I only get part of my followers list. I get a list of 136 out of 333 users that follow me. The two codes are exactly the same, and I can't seem to find the problem.

```
instagram_instance = InstagramAPI(username, password)
instagram_instance.login()

following = []
followers = []

instagram_instance.getTotalFollowers(str(instagram_instance.username_id))
result = instagram_instance.LastJson
users = result[u'users']
for user in users:
    followers.append(user[u'username'])
print followers
print len(followers)


instagram_instance.getTotalFollowings(str(instagram_instance.username_id))
result = instagram_instance.LastJson
users = result[u'users']
for user in users:
    following.append(user[u'username'])
print following
print len(following)
```

adding a link to the API: https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/blob/master/InstagramAPI/InstagramAPI.py

Comment: Links to the wrapper or the API that you're using please.

Comment: updated my post with the link.

Comment: The wrapper isn't very well-documented and I'm not a user so I can't help much. But try getSelfUsersFollowing() or getSelfUserFollowers() instead, they seem to fit what you're doing better.

Comment: @kenbroon I’ve tried it, the getSelfUsersFollowing() and getSelfUsersFollowers() functions just call getUsersFollowing() and getUsersFollowers() with a parameter. I assume the functions I use work because as I written above, the “following” list works. The only problem is with the “followers” list.